# Explanation of Big-O notation.

Tags: asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

Could someone please explain to me what the following Big-O notations mean?

[image]

What the author mean when he says that 
$|\phi(s)|=O(e^{|\tau|^\delta})(|\tau|\rightarrow \infty)$ uniformly on F?

Does it mean that $\exists M>0, \tau_0>0$ s.t $\forall \tau>\tau_0$ and $\forall s\in F$ s.t $Im(s)>\tau_0$ $|\phi(s)|\leq Me^{|\tau|^\delta}$

or is it $\exists M>0, \tau_0>0$ s.t $\forall \tau>\tau_0$ and $\forall s\in F$ $|\phi(s)|\leq Me^{|\tau|^\delta}$

I am just confused with the uniformly part.

I have a similar issue with the statement below:

[image]

Can someone please provide a rigorous definition of the O and ~ notations above?

Comment: Intuitively, $O$ means "doesn't grow faster than" and $\sim$ is "asymptotically equal to" (i.e. the ratio tends to $1$). https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Formal_definition

Comment: Thanks but what does the uniformly part mean and is my definition correct?

Comment: It means uniformly with respect to $\sigma$. I.e. That there is an $M$ and a $\tau_0$ such that *for all $\sigma$* and $\tau$ with $\sigma + i\tau \in F$ and $|\tau| > \tau_0, \phi(|\sigma+i\tau)| < Me^{|\tau|^\delta}$. The values of $M$ and $\tau_0$ do not need to be dependent on $\sigma$.